# How to use GradientTape with AutoGraph in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I can not figure out how to run GradientTape code on AutoGraph in Tensorflow 2.

I want to run GradientTape code on TPU. I wanted to start by testing it on CPU. TPU code would run much faster using AutoGraph. I tried watching the input variable and I tried passing in the argument into the function that contained GradientTape but both failed.

I made a reproducible example here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1luCk7t5SOcDHQC6YTzJzpSixIqHy_76b#scrollTo=9OQUYQtTTYIt

The code and the corresponding output is as follows:
They all start with `import tensorflow as tf`

```py
x = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)
print(dy_dx)
```

Output: `tf.Tensor(6.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)`
Explanation: Using Eager Execution, the GradientTape produces the gradient.

```py
@tf.function
def compute_me():
    x = tf.constant(3.0)
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
      g.watch(x)
      y = x * x
    dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x) # Will compute to 6.0
    print(dy_dx)
compute_me()
```

Output: `Tensor("AddN:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`
Explanation: Using AutoGraph on GradientTape in TF2 results in empty gradient

```py
@tf.function
def compute_me_args(x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
      g.watch(x)
      y = x * x
    dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x) # Will compute to 6.0
    print(dy_dx)    
x = tf.constant(3.0)
compute_me_args(x)
```

Output: `Tensor("AddN:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`
Explanation: Passing in arguments also fails

I was expecting all of the cells to output `tf.Tensor(6.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)` but instead the cells using AutoGraph output `Tensor("AddN:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't "fail", it's just that `print`, if used in the context of a `tf.function` (i.e. in graph mode) will print the symbolic tensors, and these do not have a value. Try this instead:

```
@tf.function
def compute_me():
    x = tf.constant(3.0)
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        g.watch(x)
        y = x * x
    dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x) # Will compute to 6.0
    tf.print(dy_dx)
compute_me()
```

This should print `6`. All you need to do is use `tf.print` instead, which is "smart" enough to print the actual values if available. Or, using return values:

```
@tf.function
def compute_me():
    x = tf.constant(3.0)
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        g.watch(x)
        y = x * x
    dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x) # Will compute to 6.0
    return dy_dx
result = compute_me()
print(result)
```

outputs something like `<tf.Tensor: id=43, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=6.0>`. You can see that the value (6.0) is visible here as well. Use `result.numpy()` to just get `6.0`.

Comment: Tested the code samples and they work on Tensorflow `2.0.0-rc0` and Tensorflow `2.0.0-beta1`.